# Execute PHP Script through Crontab Qnap NAS

Tags: php, shell, cron, nas

Im trying to run a Script with Cron:

The Cron I used:

```
ssh: crontab /test.txt
```

test.txt:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script/cron/dashboard.php
```

(I set the Interval to every minute to check if it works)

dashboard.php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","myuser","mypw","mydb");
$randomnumber = rand(1000,3000);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO dashboard (count, date)
VALUES ('$randomnumber', NOW())");


mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I inserted the crontab via `crontab /test.txt` (located in root).

Then executed this line (I followed this tutorial: [Qnap Turorial for Crontabs](http://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/Add_items_to_crontab)):

`/etc/init.d/crond.sh restart`

And I tried to open the Script in a Browser and it worked (I had a new row in my table with a random number and the current date.
But If I check my Database every minute nothing new is added through the cron tab..

I run the System through my QNAP NAS...

Comment: Your current settings tell it to run every hour at minute 1, if you want it to run every minute change settings to 

    * * * * * /path/to/script/cron/dashboard.php

Comment: oh sorry I changed it but still nothing happens..

Comment: I think the problem is that Cron cannot 'open' the script?

Answer (score 3):

You could try to edit the default crontab directly:

1. Edit `/etc/config/crontab` via WinSCP or open it with `crontab -e`
2. Add your entry `* * * * * /path/to/script/cron/dashboard.php`
3. Execute the command `crontab /etc/config/crontab`
4. And finally restart the cron-service with `/etc/init.d/crond.sh restart`

After those steps, the cron-service should execute the cron-jobs.

Comment: from the qnap wiki page https://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/Add_items_to_crontab it seems that "crontab -e" is not the right way to edit the crontab. Go with the vi/nano option on /etc/config/crontab